# Am I misusing mpi_file_write_all?

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmpi, mpi-io

I have a snippet of code writing data in a file with MPI-IO. It works well when I am using `mpi_file_write`, but if I switch to the collective `mpi_file_write_all` I get the wrong result.  Do I have to change more than just the call to the write function to use the collective writing routine?

With `mpi_file_write` the file contains the expected result, 4 lines of the form "1 2 3 4".

```
$od -f TEST  
0000000               1               2               3               4  
*  
0000100
```

But with `mpi_file_write_all` the result file is different: the data are in the wrong order:

```
$od -f TEST  
0000000               1               1               2               3  
0000020               2               4               3               4  
0000040               1               2               1               3  
0000060               2               3               4               4  
0000100
```

So I am wondering if I have done something wrong. Is there some difference between `mpi_file_write` and `mpi_file_write_all` that I have missed?

I am using the version 3.0 of OpenMPI.

```
      PROGRAM INDEXED
      USE MPI
      IMPLICIT NONE
      REAL :: A(4)
      INTEGER :: INDEXTYPE,FH,IERR,L,N
      INTEGER(KIND=MPI_OFFSET_KIND) :: OFFSET
      CHARACTER(LEN=MPI_MAX_LIBRARY_VERSION_STRING) :: VERSION

      N=4
      A(1)=1.0
      A(2)=2.0
      A(3)=3.0
      A(4)=4.0

      CALL MPI_INIT(IERR)
      CALL MPI_GET_LIBRARY_VERSION(VERSION,L,IERR)
      WRITE(*,*)TRIM(VERSION)
      CALL CREATE_TYPE(INDEXTYPE,N)

      CALL MPI_FILE_OPEN(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "TEST",
     &  MPI_MODE_RDWR+MPI_MODE_CREATE, MPI_INFO_NULL,FH,IERR)
      CALL MPI_CHECK_CALL(IERR)

      OFFSET=0
      CALL MPI_FILE_SET_VIEW(FH, OFFSET,MPI_REAL,
     &                       INDEXTYPE,'NATIVE',
     &                       MPI_INFO_NULL, IERR)
      CALL MPI_CHECK_CALL(IERR)

      CALL MPI_FILE_WRITE(FH,A,N,MPI_REAL,
     &                    MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,IERR)
      !CALL MPI_FILE_WRITE_ALL(FH,A,N,MPI_REAL,
      !&                        MPI_STATUS_IGNORE,IERR)

      CALL MPI_CHECK_CALL(IERR)
      CALL MPI_FILE_CLOSE(FH,IERR)
      CALL MPI_CHECK_CALL(IERR)

      CALL MPI_FINALIZE(IERR) 
      END PROGRAM INDEXED

      SUBROUTINE CREATE_TYPE(DATARES_TYPE,N)
        USE MPI
        IMPLICIT NONE
        INTEGER, INTENT(OUT) :: DATARES_TYPE
        INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: N
        INTEGER :: IERR, MY_RANK
        INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: BLOCKLENS(:), DISPLACEMENTS(:)
        ALLOCATE(BLOCKLENS(N))
        ALLOCATE(DISPLACEMENTS(N))
        BLOCKLENS = 1
        CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MY_RANK, IERR)
        IF(MY_RANK==0)THEN
          DISPLACEMENTS(1)=0
          DISPLACEMENTS(2)=5
          DISPLACEMENTS(3)=2
          DISPLACEMENTS(4)=3
        ENDIF
        IF(MY_RANK==1)THEN
          DISPLACEMENTS(1)=4
          DISPLACEMENTS(2)=1
          DISPLACEMENTS(3)=6
          DISPLACEMENTS(4)=7
        ENDIF
        IF(MY_RANK==2)THEN
          DISPLACEMENTS(1)=8
          DISPLACEMENTS(2)=9
          DISPLACEMENTS(3)=14
          DISPLACEMENTS(4)=11
        ENDIF
        IF(MY_RANK==3)THEN
          DISPLACEMENTS(1)=12
          DISPLACEMENTS(2)=13
          DISPLACEMENTS(3)=10
          DISPLACEMENTS(4)=15
        ENDIF

        CALL MPI_TYPE_INDEXED(N, BLOCKLENS, DISPLACEMENTS,
     &                        MPI_REAL, DATARES_TYPE, IERR)
        CALL MPI_CHECK_CALL(IERR)
        CALL MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(DATARES_TYPE, IERR)
        CALL MPI_CHECK_CALL(IERR)
        DEALLOCATE(BLOCKLENS)
        DEALLOCATE(DISPLACEMENTS)
      END SUBROUTINE

      SUBROUTINE MPI_CHECK_CALL(IERR)
        USE MPI
        IMPLICIT NONE
        INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: IERR
        INTEGER :: NERR, RESULTLEN
        CHARACTER(LEN=MPI_MAX_ERROR_STRING) :: SERR
        IF(IERR /= MPI_SUCCESS) THEN
          CALL MPI_ERROR_STRING(IERR,SERR,RESULTLEN,NERR)
          WRITE(*,*)SERR
          CALL BACKTRACE
        END IF
      END SUBROUTINE
```

Comment: I've indented assuming you're writing as fixed-form code.  I've no idea why you'd choose to do that for Fortran 90+ code, so if I'm mistaken, please roll-back that edit (and correct the line continuation, etc.).

Comment: Can you try again with `mpirun —mca io romio314 ...` ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I tried this example with the option you've suggested and it made the example crashed, either with `mpi_file_write` or `mpi_file_write_all`. The message complains about a "double free or corruption", and the backtrace locates the crash when `mpi_file_write` (or mpi_file_write_all`) is called.

Comment: @francescalus Ok thanks. I wrote this small example with the same style I must use when I modify the software I'm working on, which use new features of fortran but sadly have an old ident style. So just the force of habit for this example.

Comment: Ok, i’ll have a look at it.

Comment: Which file system are you running on ?

Comment: Nothing fancy, just ext4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `MPI_File_set_view()` correctly indeed.
From the standard (MPI 3.1, chapter 13.3) (thanks to Wei-keng Liao for the pointer)

> An etype (elementary datatype) is the unit of data access and
>   positioning. It can be any MPI predefined or derived datatype. Derived
>   etypes can be constructed by using any of the MPI datatype constructor
>   routines, provided all resulting typemap displacements are
>   non-negative and monotonically nondecreasing.

Your derived datatype does not meet the requirement on (at least) ranks `1` and `3`

FWIW,

- the program crashes if using ROM-IO from MPICH, and i reported the issue at https://github.com/pmodels/mpich/issues/2915, and ROM-IO should really return with an error message.
- the program crashes/hangs with the latest Open MPI v3.0.x (which uses ompio by default), but works fine with the v3.1.x and master branches. Note the right fix is to fix your code, and future Open MPI versions will error in a near future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your investigations and your time! I'm gonna fix my code.